# MaxScale tries to authenticate users in all servers

Tags: maxscale

I'm trying to test if we could use MaxScale 2.4 to add multiple MySQL servers to an existing application and route the queries to the appropriate server using the schema name.

I have set skip_authentication=true to let the MySQL servers handle authentication.

We use vault to create temporary users. When I add a user to one of the servers using vault, I can connect to MaxScale using the mysql cli; but when I try to run a query, it fails because MaxScale is trying to authenticate the users in all servers and it only exists on one of them.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior in MaxScale 2.4 but was changed in 2.5 to allow authentication on only a subset of servers ([MXS-760](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-760)).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't test with version 2.5 because there are still no containers available on dockerhub.

Comment: The 2.5 docker images should be out shortly.